# Is there any Podio Webhook Verification logs?

Tags: podio

Since this morning, many webhooks were **unverified** and we are unable to verify them. These webhook worked for 2+ months. Our server does not log any POSTs from Podio (when we try to verify), but it logs any other POSTs from other sources as successful 2xx status code in a timely manner. The URL is **not** https.

**How can we find out why a Webhook wasn't successfully verified? Is there any logs?**

[image: Podio Webhooks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Podio doesn't store logs for hooks :(

Hook might be un-validated if your service was too slow or down. Podio expects that hook handler is async and simply acknowledge receiving the hook notification. Here is quote from https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks.

> The hook must respond with a 2xx status code. If the status code is
>   different from 2xx more than 50 consecutive times the hook will return
>   to being unverified and will have to be verified again to be active.
>   Additionally, your hook may return to unverified if you do not send
>   responses in a timely manner. You should handle any heavy processing
>   asynchronously.

Is there a chance that your service was down or slow recently, may be related to Amazon S3 service disruption on Tuesday (https://aws.amazon.com/message/41926/)?

Comment: It is possible yes, but it wouldn't explain why clicking verify wouldn't succeed. As of one hour ago, the Verify button works once again. It possibly was a hiccup with the API service?
The question remains though, is there any way to see logs to know what the server replied to Podio when attempting to verify a hook?

Comment: I've updated answer: Podio doesn't store webhooks logs :(. From http://status.podio.com/ it seems that there were no hiccups last 24hours, but there might be something yesterday